# Prevent 3rd party library from being bundled by easy-webpack (in Aurelia starter app)

Tags: node.js, webpack, aurelia

I'd like to base an Aurelia project on this skeleton-esnext-webpack starter app:
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack

But my question is, how to exclude libraries from being bundled by easy-webpack? You can see the problem just by adding a typical server-side library like this Postgres client:

`npm install pg-promise --save`

Then when running `npm start` (you don't even have to reference pg-promise from your code) it will puke exceptions and there is no point trying to solve this as the correct solution is to exclude pg-promise from being bundled by easy-webpack. Any examples of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late, but I came across this while trying to find the answer for the same problem. For anyone else experiencing this, you will find the answer [here](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin#includedependencies).

Basically, **aurelia-webpack-plugin** will import all the dependencies listed in your `package.json`. Luckily, there's a way around this and it's pretty simple. You only need to add:

`"aurelia": {
    "build": {
      "includeDependencies": "aurelia-*"
    }
  },`

inside `package.json`. If you are using one of the **skeleton navigation** starters, the `aurelia` key will already be there but you have to add `"includeDependencies": "aurelia-*` next to `"resources" : []`

Comment: Yes, I found that setting. I ended up excluding the pg-promise library like this as I have a lot of other dependencies I want to include and this way I don't need to list every single of them:

`"includeDependencies": [
        "!pg-promise"
      ]`